# Display PHP error in Android

Tags: php, android

I have an app that connects to a MySQL database using AsyncTask.  I can connect to the database and enter data just fine.  But I would like to know if theres a way to return an error message generated from PHP to an Android Toast.

I.E. Email address aready exists

Android Code(if needed)

```
 private class InsertData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean>
{
    ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(Register.this);

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        dialog.setMessage("Sending Data...");
        dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... urls)
    {
        for(String url1 : urls)
        {
            try
            {
                ArrayList<NameValuePair> pairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("fname", fname));
                pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lname", lname));
                pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));

                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url1);
                post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(pairs));

                HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
            }
            catch (ClientProtocolException e)
            {
                Toast.makeText(Register.this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return false;
            }
            catch(IOException e)
            {
                Toast.makeText(Register.this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result)
    {
        if(result == true)
        {
            Toast.makeText(Register.this, "Insert Success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(Register.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

PHP Code(if needed)

```
<?php

if( isset($_POST['fname']) && isset($_POST['lname']) &&   isset($_POST['email'])))
{
$lnk1= mysqli_connect("localhost", "admin", "pass") or die("Couldnt connect to SQL SERVER");
//die("Connected to SERVER");
mysqli_select_db($lnk1, "my_db") or die("Couldnt select db");
//die("Connected to DATABASE");

$reg = $_POST['reg'];
$fn = strip_tags($_POST['fname']);
$ln = strip_tags($_POST['lname']);
$em = strip_tags($_POST['email']);

/*Register Code
if($reg)
{
    $reg_errors = "";


    $e_check_rows = mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($lnk1, "SELECT email FROM users WHERE email = '$em'"));

    if(strlen($em)>0 && $e_check_rows >0)
        $reg_errors.="$em has already been registered";
    if(strlen($em)>0 && (!preg_match("#[@]#", $em)||!preg_match("#[.]#", $em)||!preg_match("#^[a-zA-Z0-9.@_-]+$#", $em)))
        $reg_errors.="$em is not a valid email address";

    echo $reg_errors;

    if(empty($reg_errors))
    {
        */
        //encryt password
        $salt = dechex(mt_rand(0, 2147483647)).dechex(mt_rand(0, 2147483647));
        $password = hash('sha256', $pw . $salt);

        for($round = 0; $round < 65536; $round++)
        {
            $password = hash('sha256', $password.$salt);
        }

        //users entry
        mysqli_query($lnk1, "INSERT INTO users (fname, lname, email) VALUES ('$fn', '$ln', '$em')");

    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Of course. You can let echo() the php script whatever you want. But you have to read those echos from the inputstream on the client. You are doing nothing with those echos as you are not reading them. Having read them you can toast them in onPostExecute.

Answer (score -1):

SQL should solve your problem.  I would query your database to check if the field entered already matched an email stored in your DB.

For instance

```
$chkuser = "select from users
where email = '$em'";
$cku = $dbc->query($chkuser);
```

Since $em is what is being used in your insert.  I'd run this check *before* you enter the data.  Just check the variable against the results of the query check `num_rows`  If the results are greater than 0 you can deliver an error.  Like so

```
$num = $cku->num_rows;
if ($num == 0) {
   //execute the query you already have listed
   }
else {
   //error message
}
```

Comment: I've got a feeling I'm gonna need to use some JSON objects to pull this off

Comment: Is this the full code for Android?  I can't see where the interface is

Comment: Full php only the async class for Java.

Comment: ok, sorry I can't help more. Just as an fyi, your php code is vulnerable to sql injection.   I recommend preparing your query before insert.

Comment: I added strip_tags to stop that I thought

Comment: Those are okay, but it's better to prepare the query  (which will eliminate type 1 and 2 attacks), and you never need to worry about escaping your variables.   Check this out:  http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp